# Filter Powershell Script for Enabled Computer Accounts Odd Results

Tags: powershell

```
Search-ADAccount -AccountInactive -ComputersOnly -TimeSpan 359.00:00:00 -Searchbase "OU=Disabled Computers,DC=mydomain,DC=net"
```

When filtering the previous script with `Where {$_.enabled -eq 'false'}` I get no results.

But when filtering with `Where {$_.enabled -ne 'true'}` I get the expected results.

Anyone know why this would be??

Comment: can you confirm that the `.enabled` property equals `false`?

Comment: Yes the property equals false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `enabled` property isn't the string `False`. But is a Boolean value that gets formatted as a string when displayed. For example, if you evaluate `$false` you'll receive back what looks like the string `False`. But if you evaluate `$False | Get-Member` you will see that `TypeName: System.Boolean`

That means that you should compare to `$False` rather than `"False"`

```
$InactiveComputers = Search-ADAccount -AccountInactive -ComputersOnly -TimeSpan 359.00:00:00 -Searchbase "OU=Disabled Computers,DC=mydomain,DC=net"
#Displaying that enabled property is System.Boolean
$InactiveComputers[0].enabled | Get-Member
$InactiveComputers | Where {$_.enabled -eq $False}
```

Edit:

Alternatively, by switching the order of the compare you can dynamically cast `$False` to the string. This is the difference between `"False" -eq $False` and `$False -eq "False"`

```
$InactiveComputers = Search-ADAccount -AccountInactive -ComputersOnly -TimeSpan 359.00:00:00 -Searchbase "OU=Disabled Computers,DC=mydomain,DC=net"
$InactiveComputers | Where {"False" -eq $_.enabled}
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you very much

Comment: If an answer worked for you, it is best practice to accept it.

Comment: I tried to upvote it and can't because I'm below 15. I thought that applied to accepting it as well.